# How to limit a search to the current line

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, search

I'm trying to write a mapping that will let me move around 'common' insertion points in a line when in insert mode. For example, I have the delimitMate plugin - so typing a opening delimiter automatically closes the delimiter and puts me in between. Once I've typed the text that goes inside, I usually want to jump to the end of the delimiter and stay in insert mode.
Taking this forward, for a function like below

```
 $("#someid").live("someevent", function (param1, param2) {
```

What I'd like is a insert mode mapping that lets me jump to after the first of any of the following delimiter chars (quote, double quote, parens, and/or EOL) and cycle over these points.

Checked VIM documentation for search - the \%l operator allows to restrict over a specific line number. I tried \%.l (. being current line ) - but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
:exe  "/\\%" . line(".") . "l[{}()\"':=\\[\\],]"
```

seems to work - but doesn't move the cursor to the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this to work with the following.

```
inoremap <C-e> <C-o>:call search("\\%" . line(".") . "l[{}():=\\[\\]\.,]","We")<cr>
```

This moves the cursor to the matches on the current line, but there are two things that don't work well:

1. there's a long pause everytime I hit the key
2. It drops me in Ins mode before the matching character instead of after as I'd like.